# Why is there a white space between parent div and inner div in react?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have this very simple component in React. I am somewhat new to react.I tried everything to remove the white space but am not able to figure out what is causing the white space to appear. Only margin negative seems to be aviable solution but I know thats not appropriate to use please tell me how to fix it
 import React, { Component } from 'react';

```
class Shopdetail extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={            
            data: this.props.data,
            redirect:false

        };        
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        console.log(this.props.match.params.idUser);
    }
        render(){
            return(
                <div style={{ verticalAlign: 'top',margin:'0',clear:'both'}}>
                    <div style={{background:'#cc5',width:'100%',height:'100px',verticalAlign: 'top',boxSizing: 'border-box',clear:'both',padding:'0'}}>Hey</div>
                </div>

            )
        }
}
export default Shopdetail
```

Here is screenshot
[image: this is screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove margin from body or simply add

```
body{
   margin : 0px !important;
}
```

Comment: did that already

Answer (score 0):

Every browser has default stylesheet for every element.

Think about, how font size of `h1` tag bigger than `p` tag...!! This stylesheet is called `User Agent StyleSheet`.

This `User Agent StyleSheet` has default margin & padding for every tag (diffrent padding & margin for diffrent tag).

A Better way is alway reset those padding & margin by universal selection after starting project.

```
*,
*:after,
*:before {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

Comment: did this but doesn't help?

Comment: Add it in you root stylesheet

Comment: the above answer helped

Answer (score -1):

Try using this css reset... add to the top of your css

```
<style>
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Please explain in detail. A link to an answer does not answer the question

Comment: try adding the this to the top of your css:
https://jsfiddle.net/d2atoqb5/

Comment: updated above with css